# During college I was in an accident, changed majors & took a tough schedule, my GPA is low & no recs from a prof, is grad school still an option?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics

I was in an accident during college, and I graduated with a low GPA (just under 3.0 or so). I switched majors to Math and while I did well in some classes, in general I was a B/C student or so. I think if I went at a normal pace, I could have done much better. Since graduating I've worked as a statistician and a computer programmer. I don't have ANY profs to ask for a letter, but I think I have an employer reference.

Can stellar GREs help me get into a Math PhD?

Comment: Stellar GREs can help, but recommendations are very important and in most programs, grades matter quite a bit. In a case like yours, a masters degree can often offer a way to reset your record and give you the portfolio you need to get into a good PhD program.

Comment: @Corvus - write your comment as an answer n

Comment: Done! I'm still learning what deserves to be an answer versus what should be left as a comment.

Comment: @Corvus I think you're doing good, so is IainDunning. Both answers deserve upvotes.

Comment: Comments are meant to be short-lived questions for clarification or discussion. They can be deleted at any time. Answers are archival.

Answer (score 6):

Stellar GREs can help but they won't get you into a top tier program on their own.  Recommendations from faculty who know you are very important, academic research experience is desired, and in most programs grades matter quite a bit. That's the bad news.

The good news is that there's a fairly straightforward way to address the situation. In a case like yours, a masters degree can often offer a way to reset your record and give you the portfolio you need to get into a good PhD program. You'll get a chance to show your ability in the classroom, you'll presumably get some research experience, and you'll have the opportunity to get to know a number of faculty well enough that they can write strong letters on your behalf.

Comment: A related option would be to start taking courses as a part time graduate student before applying to enter a program as a full time student.  At many institutions it's relatively easy to get admitted as a part time student on some kind of provisional basis.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mathematician, but I think a "stellar" score on the GRE Mathematics Subject Test would be essential, especially in the absence of recommendations or undergraduate grades.

To elaborate, admissions to a doctoral program are made on the basis that the student has a good chance of succeeding in the doctoral program and developing into a quality researcher in the field. This can be hard to determine for someone coming out of undergraduate (or industry), so proxies are used like grades/GRE, recommendations, undergraduate research projects. With only one of the pieces of this puzzle, it'd be a risky pick for an admissions committee. A masters degree would fill this gap, and the bar for admissions could be a lot lower.